# All Branches are missing in junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, hashcode

While i am trying to do code coverage for a hash code, i am getting a red indication, i.e. all 2 branches are missing.

```
 public class Phone implements Serializable {

    private String title;

    public Phone() {

    }

    public Phone(String title) {
        this.title=title;

    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you performing the coverage? Which code is executing? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @Magnilex plz chick it out.

Comment: You will need two tests, one with a title and one with title = null.

Comment: Henry, can you help me to get out of it.